# Is there any way to get the data from node on "child_added" event using cloud-function of firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I was using the query "OnUpdate" on each client to get the data from that node and calculate the children-count but it is too costly.

So I decided to use a cloud-function and create another node of children-count based on the node in which all the users exist but there is an issue, I'm unable to find any query like "OnChildAdded".

The available queries listed on firebase documentation are "OnUpdate", "OnDelete", "OnWrite" and "OnCreate" that are useless for this case because using "OnCreate" on child node cannot return me the children of parent node or "OnUpdate" on parent node will again become costly because all the users update their states frequently.

So what about "OnOperation"? Is there any use of it or is there any other way to reduce the cost of query and also create a children-count node?

Here is the structure of my database

```
{
 currentGame: {
  players: {
   playerId: {...playerGameData},
   //,
  },
  noOfPlayer: // this is what i wanted to create based on above players node children_count.
 }
}
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time following what your problem is. It might be easier to help if you show the actual code of your operation, and where you are stuck.

Comment: In the meantime, you might want to have a look at this sample for Cloud Functions that keeps a counter of child nodes: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/child-count/functions/index.js

Comment: Don't post bocks of code in comments please. Instead, click the `edit` link under your question to add the additional information (and format it).

Comment: Alright will edit it

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I've edited the question, please take a look

Comment: What you are trying to create seems feasible, and is in fact pretty close to what the code I linked does. What's the problem you have implementing this? And again: showing code here is likely to be clearer and describing the problem in words.

Comment: Thank you @FrankvanPuffelen. 
Your above sample worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution to the above problem in case anyone else need to solve a similar issue.

```
const PLAYER_REF = "currentGame/players/{playerId}";
const PLAYER_COUNT_NODE = "currentGame/noOfPlayers";

exports.incPlayersCount = functions.database.ref (PLAYER_REF).onCreate (async (snap) => 
{
    const countRef = snap.ref.root.child (PLAYER_COUNT_NODE);

    await countRef.transaction((current) => {
        return (typeof current !== "number" || current < 0) ? 1 : current + 1;
    });

    return null;
});

exports.decPlayersCount = functions.database.ref (PLAYER_REF).onDelete (async (snap) =>
{
    const countRef = snap.ref.root.child (PLAYER_COUNT_NODE);

    await countRef.transaction((current) => {
        return (typeof current !== "number" || current <= 0) ? 0 : current - 1;
    });

    return null;
});
```

btw - it is exactly similar to the sample code that @FrankvanPuffelen have shared in the above comments.